# discord.js declaration or statement expected problem

Tags: discord.js

What is wrong with this code? All the else get the problem "declaration or statement expected'. Please help me, I am new in discord.js. I needed to take all the links away to post this here.

```
  switch(args[0]){
        case 'gymlista':
            const embed0 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed0.setTitle('Gymlista')
                embed0.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed0.setURL('')
                embed0.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embed0.setDescription('En karta samt lista över alla gym i Huddinges chattar. Klicka på länken ovan!')
                embed0.setThumbnail('')
                embed0.setTimestamp('')
                embed0.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                msg.channel.send(embed0);
            break;
        case 'hjälp':
            const embedh = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embedh.setTitle('Allmänt')
                embedh.setColor('#0099ff')
                embedh.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embedh.setDescription('POGO HUDDINGE BOT är skapad och programmerad av @Pushos och är avsedd till Pokémon Go Huddinges discord server. Kontakta gärna mig om du har några frågor eller funderingar. :blush:')
                embedh.setThumbnail('')
                embedh.setTimestamp('')
                embedh.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embedh.addField('Version', 'v. 1.0 5');
                embedh.addField('Datum skapad', '26/12 -2019')
                embedh.addField('Skapad av', '@Pushos')
                embedh.addField('Prefix', '!')
                embedh.addField('Fungerar i (kanal)', '#botcommands')
                msg.channel.send(embedh);
            const embedh2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embedh2.setTitle('Commands')
                embedh2.setColor('#0099ff')
                embedh2.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embedh2.setDescription('Nedan kommer en lista över alla commands som går att använda med denna bot. Alla commands skrivs i kanalen #botcommands med ett ! innan kommandot.')
                embedh2.setThumbnail('')
                embedh2.setTimestamp('')
                embedh2.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över alla commands, samt information.', '');
                embedh2.addField('!hittagym <gymnamn>', 'Tar upp vägbeskrivning över gymmet du letar efter.');
                embedh2.addField('!gymlista', 'Karta samt lista över alla gym i Huddinges chattar.')
                msg.channel.send(embedh2);
            break;
        case 'hittagym':
            if(args[1] === 'Asmunds'){
                if(args[2] === 'häst'){
                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed.setTitle('Asmunds häst')
                embed.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed.setURL('')
                embed.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embed.setDescription('**EX Raid Gym**')
                embed.setThumbnail('')
                embed.setTimestamp('')
                embed.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embed.addField('Nära:', 'Fullersta gårdsväg 18');
                embed.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23911, 17.97408')
                embed.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                msg.channel.send(embed);
            }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Sjödalsparkens'){
                    if(args[2] === 'Utomhusscen'){
                    const embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed2.setTitle('Sjödalsparkens Utomhusscen')
                    embed2.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed2.setURL('')
                    embed2.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed2.setDescription('**Ex Raid Gym**')
                    embed2.setThumbnail('')
                    embed2.setTimestamp('')
                    embed2.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed2.addField('Nära:', 'Klockarvägen 2');
                    embed2.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23698, 17.98447')
                    embed2.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed2);
            }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Rådsparkens'){
                    if(args[2] === 'Utegym'){
                    const embed3 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed3.setTitle('Rådsparkens Utegym')
                    embed3.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed3.setURL('')
                    embed3.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed3.setDescription('**Ex Raid Gym**')
                    embed3.setThumbnail('')
                    embed3.setTimestamp('')
                    embed3.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed3.addField('Nära:', 'Kommunalvägen 27A');
                    embed3.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23994, 17.98693')
                    embed3.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed3);
            }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Fullersta'){
                    if(args[2] === 'Bio'){
                    const embed4 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed4.setTitle('Fullersta Bio')
                    embed4.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed4.setURL('')
                    embed4.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    ')
                    embed4.setTimestamp('')
                    embed4.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed4.addField('Nära:', 'Norrängsvägen 1');
                    embed4.addField('Koordinater:', '59.24016, 17.97292')
                    embed4.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed4);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Elhus'){
                    const embed5 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed5.setTitle('Elhus')
                    embed5.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed5.setURL('')
                    embed5.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed5.setThumbnail('')
                    embed5.setTimestamp('')
                    embed5.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed5.addField('Nära:', 'Mossvägen 3');
                    embed5.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23909, 17.97096')
                    embed5.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed5);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Rådjur'){
                    const embed6 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed6.setTitle('Rådjur')
                    embed6.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed6.setURL('')
                    embed6.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed6.setThumbnail('')
                    embed6.setTimestamp('')
                    embed6.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed6.addField('Nära:', 'Britas gränd 8');
                    embed6.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23779, 17.97002')
                    embed6.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed6);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Växthus1'){
                    const embed7 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed7.setTitle('Växthus1')
                    embed7.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed7.setURL('')
                    embed7.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    ')
                    embed7.setTimestamp('')
                    embed7.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed7.addField('Nära:', 'Patron Pehrs väg 5');
                    embed7.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23631, 17.9767')
                    embed7.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed7);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Snäckan'){
                    const embed8 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed8.setTitle('Snäckan')
                    embed8.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed8.setURL('')
                    embed8.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed8.setThumbnail('')
                    embed8.setTimestamp('')
                    embed8.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed8.addField('Nära:', 'Huddinge Stationsplan 2');
                    embed8.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23691, 17.97956')
                    embed8.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed8);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Sälfontänen'){
                    const embed9 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed9.setTitle('Sälfontänen')
                    embed9.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed9.setURL('')
                    embed9.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed9.setThumbnail('')
                    embed9.setTimestamp('')
                    embed9.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed9.addField('Nära:', 'Sjödalstorget 9');
                    embed9.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23615, 17.98252')
                    embed9.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed9);
                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Mimi'){
                    const embed10 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed10.setTitle('Mimi')
                    embed10.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed10.setURL(')
                    embed10.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    embed10.setThumbnail('')
                    embed10.setTimestamp('')
                    embed10.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed10.addField('Nära:', 'Sjödalsvägen 16');
                    embed10.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23475, 17.98312')
                    embed10.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed10);
                }}else{
            if(args[1] === 'Stenfontän'){
                const embed1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed1.setTitle('Stenfontän')
                embed1.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed1.setURL('')
                embed1.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embed1.setThumbnail('')
                embed1.setTimestamp('')
                embed1.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embed1.addField('Nära:', 'Gymnasietorget 5');
                embed1.addField('Koordinater:', '59.24311, 17.99626')
                embed1.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                msg.channel.send(embed1);
            }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Stenfontän3'){


                }}else{
                if(args[1] === 'Stenfontän4'){
                }}}}
            break;
        case 'clear':
            if(!args[1]) return msg.reply('Error please define second arg')
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
        }
})
```

Comment: Absolutely **never** put multiple brackets `}}}}` on one line. You're closing **four blocks of code** in that one line - do you know which ones??

Comment: Unreal to read this :/
Put your code in block code pls

Answer (score 0):

Show pls your import block

And you have SyntaxError at **setAuthor** block in this partt of code

```
if(args[1] === 'Fullersta'){
                    if(args[2] === 'Bio'){
                    const embed4 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    embed4.setTitle('Fullersta Bio')
                    embed4.setColor('#0099ff')
                    embed4.setURL('')
                    embed4.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                    ')
                    embed4.setTimestamp('')
                    embed4.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                    embed4.addField('Nära:', 'Norrängsvägen 1');
                    embed4.addField('Koordinater:', '59.24016, 17.97292')
                    embed4.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                    msg.channel.send(embed4);
```

And this

```
              const embed7 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed7.setTitle('Växthus1')
                embed7.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed7.setURL('')
                embed7.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                ')
                embed7.setTimestamp('')
                embed7.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embed7.addField('Nära:', 'Patron Pehrs väg 5');
                embed7.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23631, 17.9767')
                embed7.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                msg.channel.send(embed7);
```